# How to export data from MariaDB on linux and import it to MariaDB on XAMPP Windows

Tags: mariadb

everyone.

In my job, for local tests I (have to) use xampp on Windows 7 (using MariaDB).

Test and production servers run linux (LAMP, "M" is for MariaDB).

I'v been trying to export data from Develop server with mysqldump. Data is actually exported but when running the aplicaction, data in response came void, I mean: data field was "" instead of usual json object.

Trying with some values in one table I realize there is a problem with charset becouse when changing a "Á" character with "A" all data came right.

I've been trying with many options of mysqldump for hours and I can't find the way to import data correctly.

I tried:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --default-character-set=utf8 --compatible=mysql40 -u 'imtheman' -p 'myDB' > MyExport.sql

mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db --no-create-info --default-character-set=utf8 --compatible=mysql40 -u 'imtheman' -p 'myDB' > MyExport.sql

mysqldump --single-transaction --no-create-db --no-create-info --skip-comments --skip-add-locks --default-character-set=utf8 --compatible=mysql40 -u 'imtheman' -p 'myDB' > MyExport.sql

mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-comments --skip-add-locks --default-character-set=utf8 --compatible=mysql40 -u 'imtheman' -p 'myDB' > MyExport.sql

mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-comments --skip-add-locks --default-character-set=utf8 --compatible=ansi -u 'imtheman' -p 'myDB' > MyExport.sql

mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-comments --skip-add-locks --default-character-set=utf8 -u 'imtheman' -p 'myDB' > MyExport.sql
```

I tried to import it with phpmyadmin (xamp) and mysql-workbench. So I don't know what else to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a good reason for using `--compatible=mysql40`?  With it, there will be no commands emitted to establish the encoding of the characters.

Plan A:  Remove that option.

Plan B:  On the target machine, be sure to establish the character set before loading.

Plan B1:  Set things in the my.cnf file

Plan B2:

```
mysql ...
SET NAMES utf8;
source dumpfile.sql
```

Since MariaDB did not exist until long after 4.0, I would expect the setting to be unnecessary.